# What does "bake" mean here?

Tags: expressions

teachers
I have a question about the use of a verb "bake" 
In this sentence "bake" may be used differntly from the way I normally understand the word.

**In fact, we use metaphors every day. They are baked right into our language.**

I looked up the word in the dictionary and found the expression "bake in/into" which means' to include as an inseparable or permanent part'. Can I accepy this definition of ' bake'  to understand the sentence above?
I also found another definition which is 'to harden by heat' but it doesn't seem like a right definition for the sentence above.
I'm very confused.  What does the sentence exactly mean? Please give me the righht definition of 'bake' in the sentence or rephrase the sentence in a easy way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Metaphors are part of our language.* (Appropriately enough, *baked into* is a metaphor . . .)

Comment: Possible duplicate: "What does 'Baked-in' mean?" [closed] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928014/what-does-baked-in-mean

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the definition you gave was right. This sentence simply means "They [metaphors]'have been incorporated' into our language."

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bake-in

Comment: Try to cite your sources.